# Bound semi H2 norm by Laplacian

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $u\in H^2(\Omega)$ where $\Omega$ is bounded domain in 2D.

Then is it possible to have following inequality?

\begin{equation}
|u|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
\end{equation}

I guess it has to be something with the elliptic regularity for Poisson equation. So, do I require $\Omega$ satisfies some properties such as Lipschitz continuous or smooth boundary?

Specifically to my case, I have B-spline space $V_h\subset H^2$ without boundary restriction and $H^2_0$ space. i.e., restriction of boundary is only piecewise polynomial.

Then is it possible to have
\begin{equation}
|u|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C\|\Delta u)\|_{L^2(\Omega)},\quad\forall u\in V_h+H^2_0(\Omega)
\end{equation}

## Edit

I found a theorem:

If $\partial\Omega$ is $C^2$, then
\begin{equation}
\|u\|_{H^2(\Omega)}\leq C(\|\Delta u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}+\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)})
\end{equation}
But in my case, the domain is square. Is there any possible way to avoid the restriction of boundary?

Comment: Your last estimate also holds in polygonal convex domains. This can be found in the book "Elliptic problems in nonsmooth domains" by Grisvard

Comment: In that book, only thing I can find is for the homogeneous Dirichlet boundary condition. Is there anything with nonhomogeneous boundary condition?