# Bound H2 norm with Laplacian reference

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Does there exist a good reference for the inequality:

$$\Vert u \Vert_{H^2(\Omega)} = \Vert D^2 u\Vert_{L_2(\Omega)} \leq C\left( ||\Delta u||_{L_2(\Omega)} +  ||u||_{L_2(\Omega)}\right),$$

where $u \in H^2(\Omega)$?

I noticed this inequality for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277379/bound-semi-h2-norm-by-laplacian), but could not find any reference that derives it. I would like to know more about the constant $C$.

Comment: Very interesting notes are those of Metafune etc.  (http://siba-ese.unisalento.it/index.php/quadmat/issue/view/758). No easy but clear and with general results.